# Resizing a allocatable array

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90

I am trying to allocate an array and want to resize the array ie., grow the array size as and when required in the program.

My sample code looks like this

```
program main
implicit none
integer, allocatable, dimension(:)::test1
integer i, c1, c2
c1=10
c2=5
allocate(test1(1:c1))
!  I basically want to do this 
!allocate(test1(c1+1:c2))
end program main
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Always uae tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Add a particular version when necessary to distinguish. Note that Fortran 90 is old, obsolete and allocatable arrays were fixed in Fortran 95 and 2003. I agree it is likely a duplicate, have you searched before asking?

Comment: Thanks for the links I found the answer